# How to read a channel post with an increase in the number of views on it in Pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I can read posts from the channel this way:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import types

chat_id = -1001878174410
api_id = 22257214
api_hash = "019bd32a22641c7c0c65833a8f283c17"

app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=api_id,
    api_hash=api_hash
)

@app.on_message()
async def my_handler(client: Client, message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id != chat_id:
        return
    print(message.text)

app.run()
```

But this method does not display that someone has read this post, the number of views remains the same. Is there a way to leave a trace that the bot has read the post?

[image: Image number of views after code launch.]

I use Pyrogram==2.0.106

I will be glad of any help, even if you won't use Pyrogram.